# MS-Access Slow Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that is pulling information from one table.  That table is rather large at 1.8 Million rows and growing by week.  The query takes quite a while to run and is problematic when pulling multiple times.  Is there any process that may speed up a query in a database with this many or more rows.  I have another one with around 5 Million rows...  The query is rather basic using a prompt to pull the rows relevant to the site number, and a prompt for between dates.

```
Arrival_ID criteria = [Select Arrival ID]
Week criteria = Between[Select week begin:] And [Select week end:]
```

Any help or direction pointing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ouch, Access.  Big dataset too.. is there any opportunity to use a real database like SQL Server (even SQL Server Express)?  I hate this kind of comment but feel compelled to make it on this occassion.

Comment: "Is there any process that may speed up a query in a database"  Indexing.  Even Access supports it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indexes on the columns Arrival_ID and Week might help.

Unless you're selecting a lot of columns from a very wide table, you should get fairly quick performance from Access on 1.8 million rows, as long as your indexes are selective.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with Kieren Johnstone - can you store the data in SQL and then use access to run the queries?

Do double check the indexes.

When you compact/repair - do it twice - make it a habit.  The second time clears up any issues set aside from the first one.